# C# Textbox textresult wouldn't show up

Tags: c#

This is the code used to check whether the first number is greater than the second, but it is not working as expected. Can anyone please suggest the reason and correct me?

```
if (txtFirst.Text == "") 
{ 
    txtFirst.Text = "0"; 

    if (txtSecond.Text == "") 
    { 
        txtSecond.Text = "0"; 
        int first = Convert.ToInt32(txtFirst.Text); 
        int second = Convert.ToInt32(txtSecond.Text); 

        if (first < second) 
        {
            txtResult.Text = "TRUE"; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            txtResult.Text = "FALSE"; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Without more context it's hard to say, but one thing that come to mind is if either `txtFirst` or `txtSecond` are equal to anything *other* than `""`, then `txtResult.Text` will never be executed.   Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger?  This is a **very** easy problem to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

Your scenario is working only if both the textboxes are blank(`""`). so it will be much better if you do like the following:

```
if (txtFirst.Text == "") {txtFirst.Text = "0";}
if (txtSecond.Text == ""){txtSecond.Text = "0";}
// it is good to check for null in this scenario since
// Convert.ToInt32() is not capable of handling null
int first = Convert.ToInt32(txtFirst.Text); 
int second = Convert.ToInt32(txtSecond.Text);
if (first < second){txtResult.Text = "TRUE";}
else{txtResult.Text = "FALSE";}
```